# Number of Partitions of n into 4 parts equals the number of partitions of 3n into 4 parts of size at most n-1.

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $n\geq 4$. Prove that the number of partitions of $n$ into 4 parts equals the number of partitions of $3n$ into 4 parts of size at most $n-1$.

I am stuck on this problem but I suspect I need to establish a bijection by possibly looking at the conjugate of the Ferrer's diagram. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You have asked enough questions here to know that the right way to ask for help is to [edit] this one to show us what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: **Hint:** A quadruple $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}^4$ with $x_1\leq x_2\leq x_3\leq x_4$ partitions $n$ if and only if $(n-x_4,n-x_3,n-x_2,n-x_1)$ partitions $3n$.

Answer (score 2):

Proof: Let $n\geq 4$. The number of partitions of $n$ into 4 parts is a solution to the system $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=n$ for $x_1\geq x_2\geq x_3\geq x_4\geq 1$. Let $y_1=n-x_4$, $y_2=n-x_3$, $y_3=n-x_2$, and $y_4=n-x_1$. We know that $x_1\geq x_2\geq x_3\geq x_4\geq 1$ which implies $-x_1\leq -x_2\leq -x_3\leq -x_4\leq -1$ and thus $n-x_1\leq n-x_2\leq n-x_3\leq n-x_4\leq n-1$. So, $1\leq y_4\leq y_3\leq y_2\leq y_1\leq n-1$. Hence $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=4n-(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)=4n-n=3n$ which yields a solution to the number of partitions of $3n$ into 4 parts of size at most $n-1$. Thus there is a bijection between the system $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=3n$ for $n-1\geq y_4\geq y_3\geq y_2\geq y_1\geq 1$ and the system $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=n$ for $x_1\geq x_2\geq x_3\geq x_4\geq 1$. Therefore, the number of partitions of $n$
into 4 parts equals the number of partitions of $3n$ into 4 parts of
size at most $n-1$.